# Please avoid trivial edits during Winter Bash

Tags: discussion, winterbash

We all love the hats,* and we covet the fashionable scarf of the [Timey Wimey hat](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/timey-wimey).

But please, make edits that you would be proud of during the rest of the year. Edits should be, as always, either substantial improvements to the post or otherwise be important.

Trivial edits on old questions not only make the baby hats cry, but also threaten the integrity of the time streams.

<sup>* Apart from our resident hat-haters.**</sup>
<sup>** May not actually hate hats.</sup>

Comment: Inspired by: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5977/2788

Comment: dammit. why can't i upvote this more?

Comment: Giving people a special hat for making trivial edits was **dumb**

Comment: @Richard I think the system for detecting trivial edits is quite naïve/primitive. Otherwise I don't see how they could still have an edit based hat without trivial edits being thrown into the mix.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Indeed. Having an edit-based hat (in general) was stupid.

Comment: Absolutely. Of course, we are all agreed that grammar, spelling, and punctuation are not trivial?

Comment: @Richard - most hats are stupid. Posting at 5pm or 0pm sharp? Seriously?

Comment: I feel like we need to not do hats next year because the edits were so ridiculous.

Comment: @WadCheber Well, they could just get rid of that one hat...

Comment: @randal'thor  I also had a problem with useless questions being asked in the hopes of getting a hat...

Comment: @WadCheber OK, maybe more than one!

Comment: Simple solution: Dunce cap for trivial edits. I wouldn't wear it, but I'd have one by now.

Comment: @MajorStackings so many would though....

Comment: Since hats are over the "featured" tag should probably be removed.

Comment: At least some old questions are getting cleaned up